# How can I hold a key down for x seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, autoit-c#-wrapper

How can I hold a key down using AutoItX.dll in C#?

I tried:

```
au3.Send("{FDOWN}");
Thread.Sleep(Int32.Parse(textBox5.Text));
au3.Send("{FUP}");
```

It doesn't work because the thread is only sleeping not holding.

```
au3.Send("{FDOWN}, 5000"); /// 5 seconds
```

That doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe a loop + a StopWatch?

Comment: Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t => au3.Send("{FUP}"));

Comment: @Viliam mhh this looks good, but dont work .. i have async tasks is that maybe the problem? but i need them async.. i added await before Task. But it just wait 5 seconds before he do something.. its like Thread.sleep

Comment: I don't know exactly what the program should do, while the key is down, 
if you want to wait for key to be released (in the main thread, or a thread where you want to use time somehow), it must be waiting in some parallel way or do the activity in parallel way. Use some timer, ContinueWith of task, etc. 
The logic of the program is worth thinking about, maybe it should be revised..

Comment: My Program schould hold the key down for a Cast on a Game. i tried the whole day some   options but its only pressing the same key multiple instead of holding ...